# Trying to make a circuit solver but can't figure out how

Tags: python

I want to make a code that the user can enter a value such as (R1+R2)//R3+R4 (Which means R1 and R2 is serial and is parallel to R3 and all of that is serial to R4)

I have been trying to find an idea as to how that could be achieved. I am pretty novice but i have two ideas.

Way number 1:
(R1+R2)/R3
R1 series to R2 which both are parallel to R3

Way number 2:
R1SP R2SP R3P
SP = Serial parallel, which means parallel to the next parallel while being serial to the one after it. P = Parallel, S = Serial and = SP Serial parallel

Tried to use indexing on the PS on the way number 2 but i just couldn't wrap my head around as to how because it would only index the first one

Comment: What you want to do is a parser. If you go for the "algebraic-like" notation, then you can use a RPN parser (a code that reformats `(R1+R2)/R3+R4` in `R1 R2 + R3 / R4 +`). This second notation (called Reverse Polish) can then be easily processed using a stack.
You can probably start from questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26191707/transform-an-algebraic-expression-with-brackets-into-rpn-reverse-polish-notatio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for advice on the program logic or just a way to encode the circuit information?

If you want to make your solver more robust and able to handle any combination of resistors in parallel/series, another possible idea is to encode the circuit as a list of tuples, where each element in the list represents composing resistors in series and each occurrence of a tuple represents where resistors are wired in parallel.

[I found this image of a resistive circuit which we can use as an example](https://www.electronicshub.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/6.-Resistors-in-Combination.png). Note: I do not have any rights to this image.

This circuit could be represented like this.

```
[R1, (R2, R4), (R3, (R5, Ra))]
```

Expanded Representation:

```
[
 R1, 
 (R2, R4), 
 (R3, (R5, Ra))
]
```

In case it isn't clear, let's look at each closed loop of the circuit.

- R1, R2, R3 - [**R1**,  (**R2**, R4),  (**R3**, (R5, Ra))]
- R1, R4, R5 - [**R1**,  (R2, **R4**),  (R3, (**R5**, Ra))]
- R1, R4, Ra - [**R1**,  (R2, **R4**),  (R3, (R5, **Ra**))]

I think this method should theoretically be able to encode any purely resistive circuit. Parsing this format in Python might be a little annoying but I think it will be doable. You'll just need to check how deep each nesting goes by iteratively or recursively checking the type(). I think recursion might be the way to go because then you can treat each sub-circuit as it's own circuit and just feed it through the same solver.

Additional advice: if the loops are not all the same length like in this example where each loop is 3 resistors, then you could either a) just pad the circuit with 0 Ohm resistors to make each loop the same length, or b) use an input like -1 to signify the end of a loop.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Your idea of representation gave me an idea to specify operations by using parentheses and brackets where parantheses means parallel formula and brackets means serial formula.  Now the user can input values

Circuit you sent would be inputted as [4,([4,4],[10,(4,4)])] and the output would be 8.8 Ohms.

Thank you for your help